# jQuery validate add rule with custom action

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm dynamically adding a rule to a jQuery validate form. This rule is dynamically added because the field name contains a variable. This is the code.

```
$('#message_' + default_language_id + '_0').rules('add', {
    required: true,
    messages: {
        required: "something is wrong."
    }
});
```

I want this rule to perform an action using an anonymous function when the form is validated. But, I can't find an option / way to do this without the function executing on document ready.

Here's an extended code snippet to put it in more context:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var default_language_id = $("#default_language_id").val();

var validator = $("#message_form").submit(function() {
tinyMCE.triggerSave();

}).validate({   
    ignore: "",
    rules: {
        publish_date: {
            check_publish_date: true,
            check_expiry_date: true
        },
        expiry_date: {
            check_expiry: true,
        }
    },

    errorElement: "span",
    errorClass: "help-block",
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.parent('.input-group').length || element.prop('type') === 'checkbox' || element.prop('type') === 'radio') {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});

$('#message_' + default_language_id + '_0').rules('add', {
    required: true,
    messages: {
        required: "something is wrong"
    },
});
```

So, what I want to end up with is something like this (this doesn't work):

```
$('#message_' + default_language_id + '_0').rules('add', {
    required: true,
    messages: {
        required: "something is wrong."
    },
    onsubmit: function(){
        alert("I am only triggered when the form errors on this rule");
    }
});
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You absolutely should **not** have the `.validate()` method inside of a `submit` handler.  This method is only used on DOM ready to **initialize** the plugin and the `click/submit` events are then handled automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

```
$('#message_' + default_language_id + '_0').rules('add', {
    my_new_rule: true
});

$.validator.addMethod("my_new_rule", function(value, element) {

    // My rule

}, "something went wrong");
```